# Debugging-fixing a function such thst the second works correctly

Tags: python

I have a function to debug that is:

```
def buggy_contains(current, new):
    for mail in current:
        if mail == new:
            return True

    return False
```

I have to fix the above function such that the second function works correctly:

```
def add_new_mail(existing, new):
    if buggy_contains(existing, new):
        return # already exists nothing to do.
    existing.append(new)
```

whenever I call the function it was appending every mail to the list and returning the list,But whenever a similar mail with uppercase letter is passed it should treat it as the same mail but it isn't.Ex:add_new_mail(mails, "a@b.com") and add_new_mail(mails, "A@b.com") should be treated as same But it is counting the second mail also.
I tried to do it by changing the second function,but only the first function should be fixed.How  can I fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is case sensitive in string comparison.

Inside `buggy_contains`, use:

```
if mail.lower() == new.lower():
```

and problem will be solved.

So the function should look like this:

```
def buggy_contains(current, new):
    for mail in current:
        if mail.lower() == new.lower():
            return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind can we replace your existing list into dictionary, that will save you lots of time when your list is bigger.

```
def add_new_mail(existing, new):
     if not existing.get(new.lower(), None):
         existing[new.lower()] = True
     else:
         print 'Exists: %s' % new

existing = dict()
for i in ['a@b.com', 'A@b.com', 'a@bb.com']:
    add_new_mail(existing, i)

print existing
```

Output:

```
Exists: A@b.com
{'a@bb.com': True, 'a@b.com': True}
```